# Using different phone numbers in whatsapp business api account

Tags: rest, api, whatsapp

Following to this documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/phone-numbers about whatsapp business accounts, it is possible to have multiple phone numbers in one account. Does someone know how you can define from which number a message is send, when sending a message to a client?
There is nothing in the api about sending messages.

following to the documentation you can read the phone numbers and their whatsapp id via

```sh
curl -X GET \
'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/your-whatsapp-business-account-id/phone_numbers' \
  -d 'access_token=your-access-token'
```

example result

```sh
{
  "data": [
    {
      "verified_name": "Jasper's Market",
      "display_phone_number": "+1 631-555-5555",
      "id": "1906385232743451",
      "quality_rating": "GREEN"

    },
    {
      "verified_name": "Jasper's Ice Cream",
      "display_phone_number": "+1 631-555-5556",
      "id": "1913623884432103",
      "quality_rating": "NA"
    }
  ],
}
```

I would expect something like a senderId field when sending a message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to a WhatsApp Business API - WhatsApp Account on Business Manager (Facebook), and WhatsApp Business API Client (docker images).

1. What you're looking at is the WhatsApp account information from Business Manager.
2. Once you've added a phone number with a verified_name, you need to download the certificate from Business Manager and use that certified to register your WhatsApp Business API client (docker containers).
3. Each client is registered with a specific phone number, so you know what phone number you're using to send the messages.
4. This is equivalent to having a separate cell phone for every separate phone number and WhatsApp app on that cell phone.

   Follow the official [WhatsApp documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/getting-started), to get more detailed information about the setup.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!